# Android Java Bluetooth data streaming to Text Edit causes UI to freeze even though ondatareceived has it's own thread and handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, bluetooth

I have an activity on my app that takes data from a micro controller over Bluetooth, then is supposed to display the data as sensor readings into text views.
The data from the micro controller comes through in real time at a pretty fast rate of knots.
Data is sent from the micro controller in packets of up to 25 bytes each, the sample rate can be set via Bluetooth from anywhere between 1 packet per second to 1000 packets per second.
As soon as data starts to be received the UI freezes up. I have put data receive handling in a separate thread from the main thread. Have no idea why its locking up the ui, here is my activity code ...

```
 public class adminConsole extends AppCompatActivity {


private Button btn_Back;
private Button btn_Send;
private Button btn_Graphical;
private TextInputEditText etmessage;
private TextView txtconsole;
private IncomingBuffer bigbuffer;
private TextView ch0;
private TextView ch1;
private TextView ch2;
private TextView ch3;
private TextView ch4;
private TextView ch5;
private TextView ch6;
private TextView ch7;
private TextView ch8;
private TextView ch9;
private TextView ch10;
private TextView ch11;
private TextView ch12;
private TextView ch13;
private TextView ch14;
private TextView ch15;

private TextView ch0s;
private TextView ch1s;
private TextView ch2s;
private TextView ch3s;
private TextView ch4s;
private TextView ch5s;
private TextView ch6s;
private TextView ch7s;
private TextView ch8s;
private TextView ch9s;
private TextView ch10s;
private TextView ch11s;

private int solCh0;
private int solCh1;
private int solCh2;
private int solCh3;
private int solCh4;
private int solCh5;
private int solCh6;
private int solCh7;
private int solCh8;
private int solCh9;
private int solCh10;
private int solCh11;

private int senCh0;
private int senCh1;
private int senCh2;
private int senCh3;
private int senCh4;
private int senCh5;
private int senCh6;
private int senCh7;
private int senCh8;
private int senCh9;
private int senCh10;
private int senCh11;
private int senCh12;
private int senCh13;
private int senCh14;
private int senCh15;
public byte[] listenerbyte;

BluetoothSPP bt;
RxBus ebus;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_console);
    ebus = new RxBus();
    bt = new BluetoothSPP(this);
    bt.startService(BluetoothState.DEVICE_OTHER);

    TextInputEditText etmessage = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.etmessage);
    TextView txtconsole = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.consoleCommsTxt);
    txtconsole.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());




    if (!bt.isBluetoothAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                , "Bluetooth is not available"
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    bt.setBluetoothConnectionListener(new BluetoothSPP.BluetoothConnectionListener() {
        public void onDeviceConnected(String name, String address) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    , "Connected to " + name
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onDeviceDisconnected() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    , "Connection lost"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onDeviceConnectionFailed() {
            Log.i("Check", "Unable to connect");
        }
    });


    bt.setAutoConnectionListener(new BluetoothSPP.AutoConnectionListener() {
        public void onNewConnection(String name, String address) {
            Log.i("Check", "New Connection - " + name + " - " + address);
        }

        public void onAutoConnectionStarted() {
            Log.i("Check", "Auto menu_connection started");
        }
    });


    if (bt.getServiceState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        bt.disconnect();
    } else if (bt.getServiceState() == BluetoothState.STATE_NONE) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceList.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, BluetoothState.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    Button btn_Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    Button btn_Send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    Button btn_Graphical = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGraphical);

    btn_Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(adminConsole.this, Admin.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });


    //  btn_Send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //    @Override
    //  public void onClick(View v) {
    //    String usrmessage = Objects.requireNonNull(etmessage.getText()).toString();
    //  bt.send(usrmessage, true);
    //txtconsole.append(usrmessage);


    //}
    //});


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    DataIncomingThread thread = new DataIncomingThread(handler);
    thread.start();


}




class DataIncomingThread extends Thread {


    private final Handler mHandler;

    TextView ch0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chZero);
    TextView ch1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chOne);
    TextView ch2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chTwo);
    TextView ch3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chThree);
    TextView ch4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chFour);
    TextView ch5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chFive);
    TextView ch6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chSix);
    TextView ch7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chSeven);
    TextView ch8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chEight);
    TextView ch9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chNine);
    TextView ch10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chTen);
    TextView ch11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chEleven);
    TextView ch12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chTwelve);
    TextView ch13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chThirteen);
    TextView ch14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chFourteen);
    TextView ch15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chFifteen);

    TextView ch0s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chZeroS);
    TextView ch1s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chOneS);
    TextView ch2s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chTwoS);
    TextView ch3s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chThreeS);
    TextView ch4s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chFourS);
    TextView ch5s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chFiveS);
    TextView ch6s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chSixS);
    TextView ch7s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chSevenS);
    TextView ch8s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chEightS);
    TextView ch9s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chNineS);
    TextView ch10s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chTenS);
    TextView ch11s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chElevenS);

    DataIncomingThread(Handler handler) {
        mHandler = handler;


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        Log.i("Data Thread", "Data Thread Launchedlistenerbyte is " + listenerbyte);

        bt.setOnDataReceivedListener(new BluetoothSPP.OnDataReceivedListener() {


            @Override


            public void onDataReceived(byte[] bytes, String message) {
                int packetlength = bytes.length;

                //   new Thread(new DataPacketUnpacker()).start();


                //while (true) {


                while (true) {
                    try {


                        //   Log.d("DEBUG BT-console", "IN CONNECTED THREAD RUN Datathread" + listenerbyte);


                        for (byte firstbyte : bytes) {

                            int i = 0;
                            firstbyte = bytes[i];

                            if (firstbyte == 90) {


                                solCh0 = (bytes[1] | bytes[2] >> 4 & 0xFF) & 0xFFF;
                                solCh1 = (bytes[2] << 8 & 0xFF | bytes[3] & 0x0F) & 0xFFF;
                                solCh2 = (bytes[4] | bytes[5] >> 4 & 0xFF) & 0xFFF;
                                solCh3 = (bytes[5] << 8 & 0xFF | bytes[6] & 0x0F) & 0xFFF;
                                solCh4 = (bytes[7] | bytes[8] >> 4 & 0xFF) & 0xFFF;
                                solCh5 = (bytes[8] << 8 & 0xFF | bytes[9] & 0x0F) & 0xFFF;
                                solCh6 = (bytes[10] | bytes[11] >> 4 & 0xFF) & 0xFFF;
                                solCh7 = (bytes[11] << 8 & 0xFF | bytes[12] & 0x0F) & 0xFFF;
                                solCh8 = (bytes[13] | bytes[14] >> 4 & 0xFF) & 0xFFF;
                                solCh9 = (bytes[14] << 8 & 0xFF | bytes[15] & 0x0F) & 0xFFF;
                                solCh10 = (bytes[16] | bytes[17] >> 4 & 0xFF) & 0xFFF;
                                solCh11 = (bytes[17] << 8 & 0xFF | bytes[18] & 0x0F) & 0xFFF;


                                // try {
                                //    DataIncomingThread.run();
                                //}catch (NullPointerException e){
                                //   Log.e("Data to textview", "No data to post");
                                // }


                                Log.i("Data Unpack -console", "Found Solenoid Syncbyte " + solCh0 + " " + solCh4 + " " + solCh7);


                            } else if (firstbyte == -91) {

                                int senCh0 = (bytes[1] | bytes[2] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh1 = (bytes[2] >> 4 | bytes[3]) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh2 = (bytes[4] | bytes[5] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh3 = (bytes[5] >> 4 | bytes[6]) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh4 = (bytes[7] | bytes[8] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh5 = (bytes[8] >> 4 | bytes[9]) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh6 = (bytes[10] | bytes[11] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh7 = (bytes[11] >> 4 | bytes[12]) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh8 = (bytes[12] | bytes[13] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh9 = (bytes[13] >> 4 | bytes[14]) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh10 = (bytes[15] | bytes[16] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh11 = (bytes[16] >> 4 | bytes[17]) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh12 = (bytes[18] | bytes[19] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh13 = (bytes[19] >> 4 | bytes[20]) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh14 = (bytes[21] | bytes[22] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                                int senCh15 = (bytes[22] >> 4 | bytes[23]) & 0xFFF;


                                // try {
                                //     DataIncomingThread.run();
                                //}catch (NullPointerException e){
                                //    Log.e("Data to textview", "No data to post");
                                // }

                                Log.i("Data Unpacker", "Found Sensor syncbyte");

                            } else {

                                //  Log.i("Data unpack", "No data to unpack" + packetlength);
                                try {
                                    txtconsole.append(message);
                                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                    //     Log.i("Data unpacker", "No console message to show");
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                        Log.e("Packet handling", "A problem decoding data is " + listenerbyte.toString());

                    }
                }


            }
        });


        // while (!DataIncomingThread.isInterrupted()) {
        //   Thread.sleep(1000);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {




                if (ch0s != null) {
                    ch0s.setText(String.valueOf(solCh0));
                }
                if (ch1s != null) {
                    ch1s.setText(String.valueOf(solCh1));
                }
                if (ch2s != null) {
                    ch2s.setText(String.valueOf(solCh2));
                }
                if (ch3s != null) {
                    ch3s.setText(String.valueOf(solCh3));
                }
                if (ch4s != null) {
                    ch4s.setText(String.valueOf(solCh4));
                }
                if (ch5s != null) {
                    ch5s.setText(String.valueOf(solCh5));
                }
                if (ch6s != null) {
                    ch6s.setText(String.valueOf(solCh6));
                }
                if (ch7s != null) {
                    ch7s.setText(String.valueOf(solCh7));
                }
                if (ch8s != null) {
                    ch8s.setText(String.valueOf(solCh8));
                }
                if (ch9s != null) {
                    ch9s.setText(String.valueOf(solCh9));
                }
                if (ch10s != null) {
                    ch10s.setText(String.valueOf(solCh10));
                }
                if (ch11s != null) {
                    ch11s.setText(String.valueOf(solCh11));
                }

                if (ch0 != null) {
                    ch0.setText(String.valueOf(senCh0));
                }
                if (ch1 != null) {
                    ch1.setText(String.valueOf(senCh1));
                }
                if (ch2 != null) {
                    ch2.setText(String.valueOf(senCh2));
                }
                if (ch3 != null) {
                    ch3.setText(String.valueOf(senCh3));
                }
                if (ch4 != null) {
                    ch4.setText(String.valueOf(senCh4));
                }
                if (ch5 != null) {
                    ch5.setText(String.valueOf(senCh5));
                }
                if (ch6 != null) {
                    ch6.setText(String.valueOf(senCh6));
                }
                if (ch7 != null) {
                    ch7.setText(String.valueOf(senCh7));
                }
                if (ch8 != null) {
                    ch8.setText(String.valueOf(senCh8));
                }
                if (ch9 != null) {
                    ch9.setText(String.valueOf(senCh9));
                }
                if (ch10 != null) {
                    ch10.setText(String.valueOf(senCh10));
                }
                if (ch11 != null) {
                    ch11.setText(String.valueOf(senCh11));
                }
                if (ch12 != null) {
                    ch12.setText(String.valueOf(senCh12));
                }
                if (ch13 != null) {
                    ch13.setText(String.valueOf(senCh13));
                }
                if (ch14 != null) {
                    ch14.setText(String.valueOf(senCh14));
                }
                if (ch15 != null) {
                    ch15.setText(String.valueOf(senCh15));
                }

                //  Log.i("UIHandler", "setText commands were called");




            }
        });
    }

}
```

Does anyone know why it freezes up? The log continues to display received data even after the ui has locked up.

**EDIT**
It seems to be the following code that causes the issue...

```
private final Handler mHandler;

    DataIncomingThread(Handler handler) {
        mHandler = handler;


    }




        @Override
        public void run () {




            bt.setOnDataReceivedListener(new BluetoothSPP.OnDataReceivedListener() {


                @Override


                public void onDataReceived(byte[] bytes, String message) {
                    int packetlength = bytes.length;

public void onDataReceived(byte[] bytes, String message) {
            int packetlength = bytes.length;

            //   new Thread(new DataPacketUnpacker()).start();


            //while (true) {


            while (true) {
                try {


                    //   Log.d("DEBUG BT-console", "IN CONNECTED THREAD RUN Datathread" + listenerbyte);


                    for (byte firstbyte : bytes) {

                        int i = 0;
                        firstbyte = bytes[i];

                        if (firstbyte == 90) {


                            solCh0 = (bytes[1] | bytes[2] >> 4 & 0xFF) & 0xFFF;
                            solCh1 = (bytes[2] << 8 & 0xFF | bytes[3] & 0x0F) & 0xFFF;
                            solCh2 = (bytes[4] | bytes[5] >> 4 & 0xFF) & 0xFFF;
                            solCh3 = (bytes[5] << 8 & 0xFF | bytes[6] & 0x0F) & 0xFFF;
                            solCh4 = (bytes[7] | bytes[8] >> 4 & 0xFF) & 0xFFF;
                            solCh5 = (bytes[8] << 8 & 0xFF | bytes[9] & 0x0F) & 0xFFF;
                            solCh6 = (bytes[10] | bytes[11] >> 4 & 0xFF) & 0xFFF;
                            solCh7 = (bytes[11] << 8 & 0xFF | bytes[12] & 0x0F) & 0xFFF;
                            solCh8 = (bytes[13] | bytes[14] >> 4 & 0xFF) & 0xFFF;
                            solCh9 = (bytes[14] << 8 & 0xFF | bytes[15] & 0x0F) & 0xFFF;
                            solCh10 = (bytes[16] | bytes[17] >> 4 & 0xFF) & 0xFFF;
                            solCh11 = (bytes[17] << 8 & 0xFF | bytes[18] & 0x0F) & 0xFFF;


                            // try {
                            //    DataIncomingThread.run();
                            //}catch (NullPointerException e){
                            //   Log.e("Data to textview", "No data to post");
                            // }


                            Log.i("Data Unpack -console", "Found Solenoid Syncbyte " + solCh0 + " " + solCh4 + " " + solCh7);


                        } else if (firstbyte == -91) {

                            int senCh0 = (bytes[1] | bytes[2] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh1 = (bytes[2] >> 4 | bytes[3]) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh2 = (bytes[4] | bytes[5] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh3 = (bytes[5] >> 4 | bytes[6]) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh4 = (bytes[7] | bytes[8] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh5 = (bytes[8] >> 4 | bytes[9]) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh6 = (bytes[10] | bytes[11] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh7 = (bytes[11] >> 4 | bytes[12]) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh8 = (bytes[12] | bytes[13] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh9 = (bytes[13] >> 4 | bytes[14]) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh10 = (bytes[15] | bytes[16] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh11 = (bytes[16] >> 4 | bytes[17]) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh12 = (bytes[18] | bytes[19] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh13 = (bytes[19] >> 4 | bytes[20]) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh14 = (bytes[21] | bytes[22] << 4) & 0xFFF;
                            int senCh15 = (bytes[22] >> 4 | bytes[23]) & 0xFFF;


                            // try {
                            //     DataIncomingThread.run();
                            //}catch (NullPointerException e){
                            //    Log.e("Data to textview", "No data to post");
                            // }

                            Log.i("Data Unpacker", "Found Sensor syncbyte");

                        } else {

                            //  Log.i("Data unpack", "No data to unpack" + packetlength);
                            try {
                                txtconsole.append(message);
                            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                //     Log.i("Data unpacker", "No console message to show");
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                    Log.e("Packet handling", "A problem decoding data is " + listenerbyte.toString());

                }
            }


        }
    });
```

For testing purposes only the first if condition returns true. I still don't know what I'm doing wrong. Checked the cpu usage with profiler and it is minimal.

Comment: Look into arrays... you don't need to have ch0, ch1, ...

Comment: Will using an array improve performance or are you suggesting this for readability only?

Answer (score 0):

So I shouldn't have had while(true), It was causing an infinite loop. The UI is still laggy but now at least values are being posted to the UI. Seems like it's still running on the main thread and not on a separate thread.